# Calculate Net Worth from Transaction data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have list of transactions of stock purchases. I am trying from that to calculate net worth. 
Table is as defined:

```
ID | DATE       | SYMBOL | SHARES | PRICE | CLOSE
-------------------------------------------------
1  | 2010-06-01 | T      |    100 | 24.35 | 24.15
2  | 2010-07-01 | RSO    |     10 |  6.25 |  6.40
......
```

Goes from 2010-Today.
So to calculate value but i multiply shares * close = value. But that only works for that day. i have another script that gives me the closing value at any day.

```
$history = getClose($symbol, $daterange)
```

returns a multidimensional array where the symbol contains the dates like below

```
$history['symbol']['20100601'] = $price
$history['symbol']['20100701'] = $price
```

i know this has to be simple i have all the pieces to the puzzle i just cant figure out how to put it together.
I also have an SQL statement that gives me all of my holdings on a given day.

```
SELECT symbol, sum(shares) AS shares, sum(shares * close) AS value 
FROM Transactions 
WHERE (action<> 5) AND date <='2010-06-01' 
    GROUP BY symbol
    HAVING (sum(shares) > 0);
```

But that only gives me the value for the days the purchases were actually made. 
Ultimately the goal is to put this in a chart showing growth(or decline) over time

Id have more code for you but literally i cant wrap my mind around how to do it.
Not that it makes a difference, but i am using codeigniter framework for the website

Comment: Can you post some more sample data with desired results?

Comment: I'm confused - You only mention the Trnasactions table... that will only give you data for the day the shares were purchased. Seems like you would also need a pricing table that had the closing price data for every share in owned on each day.

Comment: I'm lost. What was your question? Action? What's that? Are we psychic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a piece of the puzzle. Unless you are perpetually buying and never selling you'll need some way to indicate actual holdings on every day you sum. That means knowing all the changes - both buys and sells.

Two ways (that immediately come to mind):

> 1. Update the holdings table to reflect all ownership for everyday that a stock is owned. Then you can sum over everything to get total value
> 2. Track the sells somehow. Then you'll know what periods to sum over and you can loop over the date-delta for each and sum.

Since your third query is titled `Transactions` and includes some sort of `action` column you must have this data somewhere. Now you just need to get the date ranges and then sum over values for each.

Comment: Well yes my transaction table has every buy / sell / split... in their, but currently i am not tracking closing price. So i guess what i have todo is start tracking closing price? i mean i could pull it from YahooFinance API on the fly which is what i have been doing so far to calculate gain... What is the best way to store all of this data? SQL table with date, symbol and price? i can already see this table having alot of entries close to 15000. is that an issue?

Comment: Size won't be a problem as long as the hardware keeps up. 15K is nothing, though - assuming you are indexing properly. Either you track all holdings, every day or you track your buys and sells and then calculate holdings by day. You will need to know closing costs either way, though.